Ubuntu software not working - OS Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Yesterday i have upgraded OS Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS over OS Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop Dell Inspiron 3542 configuration:
RAM 8 GB,
SSD 480 GB,
Processor i3 1.7GHz x 4,
Graphic Mesa Intel 4400,
Ubuntu Pro support enabled,
The first update after the upgrade installation is saying that i have partial upgrade and in order to finish i have been offered to choose between two buttons, Partial upgrade or Continue.
Any way, what ever i choose the final response is this:
Upgrade from ,noble to jammy is not possible with this tool. So, the total upgrade of OS Ubuntu 24.04.1 seems is not finished but stuck somewhere...
Assuming, as partial upgrade, the Ubuntu Software icon is not working to download any application.
Question:
How to fix this issue, how to finish the upgrade and how to make Ubuntu Software icon to work properly?
After sudo apt update i received this message: (637 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them ) And after (apt list ---upgradable) now im seeing a lot of things to upgrade including the Noble upgrade, what other command should i type in order to upgrade Ubuntu 24.04.1. ?
*The difference is in stability of Ubuntu. Until i had Ubuntu 22.04 version everything worked fine. In the moment i allowed the upgrade to 24.04 Ubuntu as an update, since then in period of 5 days my system crashed two times. Not working at all, zero functionality. So my opinion is that Ubuntu 24.04 has some defect and that is the reason i reinstalled two times 22.04 Ubuntu. This time i will avoid any installation into 24.04. because it is not stable at all.
What do you say about this issue?



Please edit your question to show us the complete output of sudo apt update

Please avoid adding new information in comments. Please edit your original question to add new information and clarifications.

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
